# How to create global variable array in laravel 9 controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

how to make a global array variable in laravel controller

i tried this

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public $loginCred = [];

    public function postLogin(Request $request){
        $request['email'] = $loginCred['email'];
        $request['password'] = $loginCred['password'];
        // a bunch of code later
        return redirect()->away($authUrl);
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        $loginCred->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

but it gives ErrorException "Undefined variable $loginCred"

Comment: You need to access it as `$this->loginCred`. You should learn the basics before touching a framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a variable in a class, your functions need to use $this->variable to access it.
Therefore, you should use:

```
$this->loginCred
```

to access your $loginCred variable.

Answer (score -2):

If the defining process is reversed like this:

```
$loginCred['email'] = $request['email'];
$loginCred['password'] = $request['password'];
```

It works on my machine, the login passed, and the error is gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).